# unable to create DNS A record when integrating private endpoint with private dns zone

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

I  had created storage account with private endpoint using arm template. When it comes to integrating private endpoint with private dns zone , i am able to successfully associate private dns zone **but unable to create DNS A record with private ip address.**

Here is partial arm template on how i am integrating. **Am i missing something?**

```
    {

      "condition": "[not(parameters('storagepublicAccess'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccount_name'))]",
         "PrivateEndpointGroupCopy"
      ],
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', variables('privateEndpointnames')[copyIndex()], parameters('privateDnsZones')[copyIndex()])]",
      "properties": {
         "privateDnsZoneConfigs": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('privateEndpointnames')[copyIndex()],'-config')]",
              "properties": {
                "privateDnsZoneId": "[concat(subscription().id,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('dnsResourceGroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/',parameters('privateDnsZones')[copyIndex()])]"
              }
            }
         ]
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "PrivateDNSZonesCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('privateDnsZones'))]"
      }
    }
```